# How can I search the internet for phrases where each word begins with a specific letter?

Tags: elasticsearch, search-engine, mnemonics

Sometimes you have to memorize a long list or pathway (especially in medicine/biochemistry). This is much easiar if you have a mnemonic phrase to help you remember the first letter of each keyword. However, current mneomnic makers produce extremely unrealistic sentances that don't stick well in the memory.

e.g. for the colours of the rainbow: "Round Outstanding Youths Governed Blue Igor Vigilantly."

I hypothesise that using phrases that other people have actually written would stick in the head much better, especially if one could choose from a list of the most commonly used phrases starting with those letters.

Is there any way to search the internet for phrases where each word begins with a specific character?

Comment: Something like this? https://spacefem.com/mnemonics/

Comment: That's what I'm hoping to find a replacement for! It generates the right type of output, but the output itself is rarely a very memorable phrase.